# Event handler called multiple times - Socket.io-swift in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, socket.io, webrtc

right now i'm working on google webRTC (Conferencing) iOS app and using socket.io as a signaling protocol.

For individual management of signaling between users, i need to create socket per client.

At first client side i am creating two channels, one is public (for public-ally broadcasted messages) and one is my own private (using my id as a namespace). See - **"initChannel"** and **"createMyChannel"**.

when new user joins room, i get **'newParticipant'** event in public channel, using new user id i create a private channel to send private messages to that particular user's channel which is already created by that client when he/she joined the room. See - **"WRTCSignalingType"** switch case.

everything working fine except when i send message to user's private channel after receiving **'newParticipant'**, at receiver side below handler called several times

```
[self.myChannel on:@"message" callback:^(NSArray * data, SocketAckEmitter * ack) {
        NSLog(@"Data >>> %@", data);
    }];
```

i don't get it why is this happening ... is message emitting multiple times or something else or is this library's bug.

please help... it's just driving me crazy.

```
@interface WRTCMultiPeerConnection ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) SocketIOClient *channel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SocketIOClient *myChannel;

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *room;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *participant;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSURL    *socketUri;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *iceServers;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *connectionOptions;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *peerToConnectionMap;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *offerChannels;

@end

@implementation WRTCMultiPeerConnection

- (instancetype)initConferenceCallWithRoom:(NSString *)room nickname:(NSString *)nickname delegate:(id <WRTCMultiPeerConnectionDelegate>)delegate options:(WRTCMediaConfiguration *)options {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        self.delegate       = delegate;
        self.room           = room;
        self.socketUri      = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:kSocketUrl];
        self.participant    = nickname;
        self.connectionOptions = @{@"log" : @YES};

        self.peerToConnectionMap = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        self.offerChannels       = [NSMutableDictionary new];

        [self initChannel];
        [self createMyChannel];
    }

    return self;
}


#pragma mark - Socket.io

- (void)createMyChannel {

    self.myChannel = [[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:self.socketUri options:@{@"log" : @NO, @"nsp" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", self.participant]}];

    [self.myChannel on:@"connect" callback:^(NSArray * data, SocketAckEmitter * ack) {
        NSLog(@"Private channel connected.");
    }];

    [self.myChannel on:@"message" callback:^(NSArray * data, SocketAckEmitter * ack) {
        NSLog(@"Data >>> %@", data);
    }];

    [self.myChannel connect];
}

- (void)initChannel {

    self.channel = [[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:self.socketUri options:self.connectionOptions];

    [self.channel on:@"connect" callback:^(NSArray * data, SocketAckEmitter * ack) {
        NSDictionary *packet = @{kRoom : self.room,kFrom : self.participant};
        [self.channel emit:@"create_join" withItems:@[packet]];
    }];

    [self.channel on:@"room.created" callback:^(NSArray * data, SocketAckEmitter * ack) {

    }];

    [self.channel on:@"room.join" callback:^(NSArray * data, SocketAckEmitter * ack) {
        //NSLog(@"User send request to join room");
    }];

    [self.channel on:@"room.joined" callback:^(NSArray * data, SocketAckEmitter * ack) {

        //NSLog(@"Room Joined");

        if (data.count) {

            NSDictionary *message = [data firstObject];

            if (message && [message[kFrom] isEqualToString:self.participant]) {
                NSDictionary *packet = @{kType : kEventTypeNewParticipant, kFrom : self.participant};
                [self.channel emit:@"message" withItems:@[packet]];
            }
        }
    }];

    [self.channel on:@"message" callback:^(NSArray * data, SocketAckEmitter * ack) {

        NSLog(@"\n\nMessage recieved in Public channel >> %@ Data >> %@", self.participant, data);

        if (data.count) {

            NSDictionary *message = [data firstObject];

            if (message) {

                WRTCSignalingType signalType = [self signalTypeStringToEnum:message[kType]];

                switch (signalType) {

                    case WRTCSignalingTypeNewParticipant:
                    {
                        NSString *otherUserId = message[kFrom];

                        if (![self.offerChannels hasValueForKey:otherUserId]) {

                            //NSLog(@"\n\nRecieved New Participant from >>> %@", otherUserId);

                            self.offerChannels[otherUserId] = [[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:self.socketUri options:@{@"log" : @YES, @"nsp" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", otherUserId]}];

                            [self.offerChannels[otherUserId] on:@"connect" callback:^(NSArray * data, SocketAckEmitter * ack) {
                                NSLog(@"\n\nPrivate channel connected for user %@", otherUserId);

                                //NSLog(@"\n\nTotal offer channels %@", self.offerChannels);

                                NSDictionary *packet = @{kType : @"offer", kFrom : self.participant, @"sdp" : @"Test Connect"};
                                [self.offerChannels[otherUserId] emit:@"message" withItems:@[packet]];
                            }];

                            [self.offerChannels[otherUserId] connect];
                        }
                    }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }];

    [self.channel connect];
}
```

Comment: Sorry but there's something I don't understand: you put "Swift" in your title and in the tags, but you show code in Objective-C? Please explain. :) Remember you can use the [edit] button to edit your question anytime. Thank you.

Comment: @EricD sorry for that ... i am using socket.io swift library in objective-c.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift